# "What skills to take" question when the experience of this community can offer meaningful input

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Prospects of Switching from Business Analyst to Project Manager](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95268/prospects-of-switching-from-business-analyst-to-project-manager)

I put a close vote on this question as it does pretty much exactly fit our wording of a "not practical answerable question", yet that feels kind of off in this situation when this person is asking something that seems like a very practical answerable question given the skills present in this community.  This especially true as the interest in the OP seems to revolve around getting the information to make an informed decision rather than having someone tell them what to do.

I'm going to take a run at editing this to bring it a little more in line with our guidelines.  Is this the sort of question that this close reason is made to exclude and would this and other similar questions harm our community if permitted?

Comment: I'd probably follow Dukeling's [comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95268/how-to-decide-about-taking-a-job-related-to-rather-than-directly-in-the-field-yo#comment286863_95268). The last sentence is indeed generally answerable but it's also *very* broad and that doesn't work with the preceding paragraph which has the effect of limiting this to a very specific situation. You'd need to edit it to a canonical version of this question (i.e. scrap the first paragraph and narrow the scope) before we could really consider reopening.